# Ninject 3 activation context contains unexpected type information

Tags: c#, ninject

## Setup

I want to pass an instance of a cache as a dependency to one or more types. When a concrete instance of the cache is instantiated, it must be provided information about the type that will use it.

*I realize that this a common task and that injecting cache dependencies appears in various questions/answers; I'm setting up a specific problem I'm having with Ninject.*

```
interface IMethodCache { }

public class MethodCache : IMethodCache
{
    public MethodCache( Type type )
    {
        // type information is used to build unique cache keys
    }
}

public class CacheConsumer
{
    public CacheConsumer( IMethodCache cache ) { }
}
```

## Documentation

The Ninject [documentation shows how to do just that](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#using-the-request-context-in-a-factory-or-factory-method-to-do-contextual-binding) (using logging as an example):

```
class ClassThatLogs {
    readonly ILog _log;
    public ClassThatLogs(ILog log){
        _log = log;
    }
}

Bind<ILog>().ToMethod( context => LogFactory.CreateLog( context.Request.Target.Type ) );
```

The previous example shows that `context.Request.Target.Type` will contain the type information for the **type into which injection occurs**.

Furthermore, the comments on `context.Request.Target` state:

> Gets the target that will receive the injection, if any.

## Results

Based on this, I expect to see information about the instance *receiving* the injection. I setup my binding as follows:

```
kernel.Bind<IMethodCache>().ToMethod( 
  ctx =>
  {
      return new MethodCache( ctx.Request.Target.Type );
  } );
```

But the result is unexpected.

[image]

The `Type` property of `Target` is set to the type being bound (`IMethodCache`), not the "target that will receive injection" (`CacheConsumer`).

To state it another way: when the dependency is created, I need to pass the injectable's type to it.

I can obtain the desired information by using `context.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType`. However, I'm concerned because I don't know the ramifications of relying on the declaring type and—more importantly—because this seems contrary to the documentation.

## Questions

- Am I understanding the documentation correctly?
- If so, what am I doing wrong?
- If not, how can I accomplish the goal of passing type information to the constructor of my dependency (the cache)?

## Other Details

- Ninject 3.0.1.10
- Composition root is the start event of a Windows service
- I'm using the `StandardKernel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it seems that the documentation is incomplete/incorrect in this case.

you can get the "target" type information starting from `ctx.Request.Target` property but but you need to go "one step further" with using the `Member` and the `ctx.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType` as you've already noticed.

So it is completely fine to use the `context.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType` in fact if you check the mentioned [Ninject.Extensions.Loggin](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.logging) you will see the following in the

[source code](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.logging/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Logging/LoggerFactoryBase.cs#L80-L88):

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the logger for the specified activation context, creating it if necessary.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The ninject creation context.</param>
/// <returns>The newly-created logger.</returns>
public ILogger GetLogger(IContext context)
{
    return this.GetLogger(context.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType);
}
```